# Scale length of guitars

Tags: guitar, strings

Just about every guitar will have its own quoted scale length, for the open strings. But - which string is being quoted, as there will always be a difference between the strings, notably the top and bottom, of up to 0.5"?

Comment: Is this question ony about electric guitars with adjustable bridges?

Comment: @Jos Rather a question about an intonated bridge.

Comment: There is no default string like @Lazy said but if you’re curious you can measure the distance from the nut to the 12th fret then see which string most closely matches that distance between the 12th fret and the bridge on a few different instruments. You made me curious so I measured. On two guitars, an  acoustic and an electric it is closest to the high E. On a couple of basses even the G string, the shortest, is longer than the actual scale length.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy that would be consistent with what Lazy writes. The bridge saddles need to be moved slightly backwards to compensate intonation, and in a bass guitar, even the top string needs some compensation.

Answer (score 7):

There is no real ”default string“ for scale length. The scale length is the theoretical vibrating string length which is used for fret spacing, so the scale length should be twice the distance nut to 12th fret.

In reality the bridge will be placed a bit lower to compensate for the string tensioning up a bit when fretting. This effect is not uniform over all strings, which is why we have intonated bridges, essentially giving each string its own compensation.